understanding behaviour of spring data repository findAllByAAndB method
I have two tables, tableA and tableB. The columns in tableA are a, b, and c, while the columns in tableB are a, d, and e. Here, a is the primary key of tableA and a foreign key in tableB. Additionally, d is the primary key of tableB, and there is a one-to-one mapping between tableA and tableB.
I want to execute the following query using Spring Data JPA:
select ta.a, ta.b, tb.e from tableA ta 
left join tableB tb on ta.a = tb.a 
where ta.b = :b and ta.c = :c

In my repository interface, I have defined a method findAllByBAndC(String b, String c) without using the @Query annotation to run the above query. However, when I call my API and check the debug logs, I see that JPA is executing a single query multiple times. The query being run is:
select ta.a, ta.b, tb.e from tableA ta 
left join tableB tb on ta.a = tb.a 
where tb.a = :a

I could use the @Query annotation to write the custom query mentioned above, but I have two questions:

Why is this behavior occurring? Shouldn't JPA interpret my method definition findAllByBAndC(String b, String c) correctly and run the appropriate query to find all rows by b and c (it should return all columns but thats okay)?
Is there a way to resolve this issue without using the @Query annotation or writing extra boilerplate code, and just use Spring Data JPA and repository methods?

Below is the code for the scenario described:
TableA.java:
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class TableA {
    @Id
    private Long a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tableA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private TableB tableB;
}

TableB.java:
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class TableB {
    @Id
    private Long d;
    private String e;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a")
    private TableA tableA;
}

Repository Layer:
@Repository
public interface TableARepository extends JpaRepository<TableA, Long> {
    List<TableA> findAllByBAndC(String b, String c);
}

Service Layer:
@Service
public class TableAService {
    @Autowired
    private TableARepository tableARepository;

    public List<TableA> findAllByBAndCAndFilterByD(String b, String c, Long d) {
        return tableARepository.findAllByBAndC(b, c).stream()
                .filter(data -> data.getTableB() != null && data.getTableB().getE().equals(e))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

I have tried using the @Query annotation with the custom query, and I know this approach works. However, my question is to understand why this behavior is occurring and if we can achieve the behaviour i want without using @Query.
Edit:
To add some more context, this is what i am doing when i use @Query
Repository Layer:
@Repository
public interface TableARepository extends JpaRepository<TableA, Long> {
    @Query("select ta.a, ta.b, tb.e from tableA ta left join tableB tb on ta.a = tb.a where ta.b = :b and ta.c = :c and tb.d = :d")
    List<ProjectionAB> findAllByBAndC(@Param("b") String b, @Param("c") String c, @Param("d") String d);
}

Projection
public interface ProjectionAB {
   public Long getA();
   public Long getB();
   public Long getE();
}

Service Layer:
@Service
public class TableAService {
    @Autowired
    private TableARepository tableARepository;

    public List<ProjectionAB> findAllByBAndCAndFilterByD(String b, String c, Long d) {
        return tableARepository.findAllByBAndC(b, c, d);
    }
}


The problem is your code. You defined your relation as LAZY. Now when doing data.getTableB() it will need to issue a query to obtain the actual object. Writing the query will not change that, unless you add an FETCH JOIN to eagerly fetch the results.

@M.Deinum i got what you're saying. but this is when i am not using the @Query. when i use @Query and do left join to select my data, i do not need to stream or iterate so i believe a FETCH JOIN will not be needed, right?
This brings me to my second question, does giving FetchType.EAGER on parameter TableB tableB solve my issue without the need to write my own query?

Apparently you didn't get what I'm saying. A left join doesn't make a lazy fetch an eager fetch, a FETCH JOIN in your query however does (hence write your own query). You can switch to EAGER but this will only work when using findById afaik not when writing queries. I also don't really get why you aren't included the filter you are doing now in the query, why retrieve data and then abandon it. Also there is nothing wrong with writing specialized and optimized queries, in fact that should be the only proper way.

I did get the required results when i use a custom query with @Query. i updated my question with the details of what i am doing in that case. i do not stream or run a for loop and i use a projection so it works fine. i just want to know if it is possible to achieve this without writing a custom query. thank you for your patience. :)

You can use jakarta.persistence.SecondaryTable;
Snippets of working code:
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>


@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@SecondaryTable(
        name = "EMPLOYEE_EMAIL",
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employeeId")
    private String employeeId;

    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_JOINING")
    private LocalDate dateOfJoining;

    @Column(table = "employee_email", name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(table = "employee_email", name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_email")
@Data
public class EmployeeEmail {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private String employeeId;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String> {


}

Hibernate: select e1_0.employee_id,e1_0.date_of_joining,e1_1.email,e1_1.phone_number from employee e1_0 left join employee_email e1_1 on e1_0.employee_id=e1_1.employee_id

